# Variable initialization in as8088

Tags: function, assembly, x86, as88, x86-16

I'm currently writing a function that should basically just write characters from a string into variables.

When performing test prints my variables seem fine. But when I attempt to print the first variable assigned(inchar) outside of the function it returns a empty string, but the second variable (outchar) seems to return fine. Am I somehow overwriting the first variable?

This is my code:

```
_EXIT   = 1
_READ   = 3
_WRITE  = 4
_STDOUT = 1
_STDIN = 1
_GETCHAR = 117
MAXBUFF = 100

.SECT .TEXT
start:
0:  PUSH    endpro2-prompt2
    PUSH    prompt2
    PUSH    _STDOUT
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
    PUSH    4
    PUSH    buff
    CALL    getline
    ADD SP,4
    !!!!!!!!!
    PUSH    buff
    CALL    gettrans
    ADD SP,4
    ADD AX,1 !gives AX an intial value to start loop
1:  CMP AX,0
    JE  2f
    PUSH    endpro-prompt1
    PUSH    prompt1
    PUSH    _STDOUT
    PUSH    _WRITE
    SYS
    ADD SP,8
    PUSH    MAXBUFF
    PUSH    buff
    CALL    getline
    ADD SP,2
    !PUSH   buff
    !CALL   translate
    !ADD    SP,4
    JMP 1b
2:  PUSH    0               ! exit with normal exit status
    PUSH    _EXIT           
    SYS

getline:
    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    CX
    PUSH    BP
    MOV BP,SP
    MOV BX,8(BP)
    MOV CX,8(BP)
    ADD CX,10(BP)
    SUB CX,1

1:  CMP CX,BX
    JE  2f
    PUSH    _GETCHAR
    SYS

    ADD SP,2
    CMPB    AL,-1
    JE  2f
    MOVB    (BX),AL
    INC BX
    CMPB    AL,'\n'
    JNE 1b

2:  MOVB    (BX),0
    MOV AX, BX
    SUB AX,8(BP)
    POP BP
    POP CX
    POP BX
    RET
gettrans:
    PUSH    BX
    PUSH    BP
    MOV BP,SP
    MOV BX,6(BP) !Store argument in BX
    MOVB    (inchar),BL ! move first char to inchar


1:  INC BX
    CMPB    (BX),' '
    JE  1b
    MOVB    (outchar),BL !Move char seperated by Space to outchar

    MOV AX,1    !On success
    POP BP
    POP BX
    RET

.SECT .BSS
buff:
    .SPACE  MAXBUFF

.SECT .DATA
prompt1:
    .ASCII  "Enter a line of text: "
endpro:

prompt2:
    .ASCII  "Enter 2 characters for translation: "
endpro2:    

outchar:
    .BYTE   0
inchar:
.BYTE   0
charct:
    .BYTE   0
wordct:
    .BYTE   0
linect:
    .BYTE   0
inword:
    .BYTE   0
```

This is the code used to test print

```
PUSH    1       ! print that byte
PUSH    inchar
PUSH    _STDOUT
PUSH    _WRITE
SYS
ADD SP,8
CALL    printnl !function that prints new line

PUSH    1       ! print that byte
PUSH    outchar
PUSH    _STDOUT
PUSH    _WRITE
SYS
CALL printnl
ADD SP,8
```

Comment: How do you call `gettrans`?

Comment: Made an edit! I can post my entire code if that would help spot the issue.

Comment: -Michael Petch After making those suggested changes my results seem to remain the same. and if I point to address rather than contents my program returns 'r' for outchar and 'p' for inchar. I'll mess with it a little more. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: It's another function that's not currently being used its commented out. It should have no effect on things.

Comment: I shall give it a try results soon!

Comment: ....That...that worked hours of messing with this thing. Can't believe it was that simple thanks Michael. How do I check your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a number of `as88` 8088 simulator environments. But I noticed on many of the repositories of code this [bug](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hawkrives/as88/master/release.txt) mentioned:

> ```
> 1. The assembler requires sections to be defined in the following order: 
>        TEXT
>        DATA
>        BSS
>
> After the first occurrences, remaining section directives may appear in any order.
> ```

I'd recommend in your code to move the *BSS* section after *DATA* in the event your as88 environment has a similar problem.

---

In your original code you had lines like this:

```
MOV (outchar),BX
[snip]
MOV (inchar),BX
```

You defined *outchar* and *inchar* as bytes. The 2 lines above move 2 bytes (16-bits) from the *BX* register to both one byte variables. This will cause the CPU to write the extra byte into the next variable in memory. You'd want to explicitly move a single byte. Something like this might have been more appropriate:

```
MOVB (outchar),BL
[snip]
MOVB (inchar),BL
```

As you will see this code still has a bug as I mention later in this answer. To clarify - the *MOVB* instruction will move a single byte from *BL* and place it into the variable.

---

When you do a *SYS* call for Write you need to pass the address of the buffer to print, not the data in the buffer. You had 2 lines like this:

```
PUSH    (inchar)
[snip]
PUSH    (outchar)
```

The parentheses say to take the value in the variables and push them on the stack. SYS *WRITE* requires the address of the characters to display. The code to push their addresses  should look like:

```
PUSH    inchar
[snip]
PUSH    outchar
```

---

`gettrans` function has a serious flaw in handling the copy of a byte from one buffer to another. You have code that does this:

```
    MOV BX,6(BP) !Store argument in BX
    MOVB    (inchar),BL ! move first char to inchar

1:  INC BX
    CMPB    (BX),' '
    JE  1b
    MOVB    (outchar),BL !Move char seperated by Space to outchar
```

`MOV BX,6(BP)` properly places that buffer address passed as an argument and puts it into *BX*. There appears to be a problem with the lines that look like:

```
    MOVB   (inchar),BL ! move first char to inchar
```

This isn't doing what the comment suggests it should. The line above moves the lower byte (*BL*) of the buffer address in *BX* to the variable *inchar* . You want to move the byte at the memory location pointed to by *BX* and put it into *inchar*. Unfortunately on the x86 you can't move the data from one memory operand to another directly. To get around this you will have to move the data from the buffer pointed to by *BX* into a temporary register (I'll choose *CL*) and then move that to the variable. The code could look like this:

```
MOVB    CL, (BX)
MOVB    (inchar),CL ! move first char to inchar
```

You then have to do the same for *outchar* so the fix in both places could look similar to this:

```
    MOV BX,8(BP) !Store argument in BX
    MOVB    CL, (BX)
    MOVB    (inchar),CL ! move first char to inchar

1:  INC BX
    CMPB    (BX),' '
    JE  1b

    MOVB    CL, (BX)
    MOVB    (outchar),CL ! move second char to outchar
```

Answer (score 2):

The instruction `MOV (inchar),BX` stores register `BX` to the memory location labelled `inchar`.

However, `inchar` has been defined as a `.BYTE`, but `BX` is a 16-bit register, (2 bytes,) so you are writing not only `inchar` but also `outchar`.

The only reason why it appears to work in the beginning is because the 8088 is a low-endian architecture, so the low-order byte of `BX` is being stored first, while the high-order byte follows.

So, try `MOV (inchar),BL`

Comment: I have attempted that please take a look at the edits above. It didn't seem to resolve the issue, also the MOV should be MOVB (MOV doesn;t seem to compile)

Comment: `gettrans` still contains `MOV (inchar),BX`.  In any case, it is pointless to be troubleshooting this without a clear description of a) precisely what happens, and b) precisely what you expected to happen instead.  If I point at a mistake and you fix it, the problem of the original question may have been solved, and you may simply be facing the next problem with your code, but that would deserve a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: The goal of this program at this moment is to read in a line consisting of a 2 characters separated by a space. I want to grab the first character and store it in the variable (inchar) I want to grab the second variable and store it in (outchar).

Comment: Currently my program prints a prompt --> the user may enter 4 bytes (a char,a space,another char,a newline --> This data is stored in the buff  --> I then push the buff as an argument to my funtion gettrans -> gettrans MOVB the first char(BL) to (inchar) then checks for a space -> if a space is found I INC BX then MOVB the char from BL to (outchar)

Comment: And again from what I see in my code MOV (inchar),BX is not in gettrans anymore. Please refer to the new code (that has everything) not the code listed at the top. Sorry for the confusion. Not sure if I should remove the previously listed code as it would invalidate other comments.

Comment: Deandre, for future reference: when you explain things to people, (like you did to me in the comments above,) add your explanations in the question, so that they are available to everyone who is trying to answer your question. Also, when a correction is suggested which does not completely answer your question, always modify the question to apply the correction, and add a comment saying "this was so and so" so as to not invalidate existing comments and answers.